# Select tag and class and get custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a custom attribute using jquery and also select it, but i'm having a bit of trouble with it

Here is my jquery code to select the value

```
var stockId = $("tr .ui-state-highlight").select("[id]").val();
```

here is the tag i'm trying to select

```
<tr role="row" id="2" tabindex="0" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-
highlight" aria-selected="true"><td role="gridcell" style="text-align:left;" 
title="Alkaline Batteries" aria-describedby="productSetsSearchList-data_Name">Alkaline 
Batteries</td><td role="gridcell" style="text-align:left;" title="Alkaline Batteries" 
aria-describedby="productSetsSearchList-data_Title">Alkaline Batteries</td></tr>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong to select the the tr with class ui-state-highlight and then gather the custom attribute ID

Comment: just remove the space between tr and .ui-state-highlight

Comment: var stockId = $("tr .ui-state-highlight").attr("id"); you mean like this ?

Comment: like this $("tr.ui-state-highlight").attr("id");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the combined selector `tr.ui-state-highlight` to find `tr` with class `ui-state-highlight`, then use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) to get the desired attribute value

```
var stockId = $("tr.ui-state-highlight").attr("id");
```

Comment: I used your answer, I will accept it when the timer has gone away

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var stockId = $("tr.ui-state-highlight").attr("id");
```

or

```
var stockId = $("tr.ui-state-highlight").attr("your custom attribute");
```